# How to solve this crazy Chinese puzzle for children?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

[image]

I have been shown this "Chinese puzzle from textbook for 2nd grade" like a joke. But it is intriguing, so I would like to know the answer, but I am quite bad in associative puzzles and can't find the pattern.

The translation of the 3 lines of text should be the following:

> These creatures below are aliens:
>   These creatures below are not aliens:
>   Which of the following below is an alien? Circle it. (5 points)

Comment: Actually, the bottom line reads, "Which of the following below is an alien? Circle it. (5 points)"

Comment: @JoeZ., wow, you know Chinese? Thanks! That's formulation is even better)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All the creatures in the top row have three dangly things and one triangle on their body. None of the creatures in the second row do.

By that criterion, only the fourth creature in the bottom row is an alien.